# File Handler created using ctypes is invalid

Tags: python, ctypes

I was trying to create a new file using `ctypes` in python. The file gets created and I am able to write in to it. The problem starts when I try to read from this file. It gives me an invalid file handle error. Anyone might know why this is the case.

The following is the code I used:

```
from ctypes import *

def CreateFile(file_name='',data=''):

    file_handler=windll.Kernel32.CreateFileA(file_name,0x10000000,0,None,4,0x80,None)

    pointer_to_written_data=c_int(0)
    windll.Kernel32.WriteFile(file_handler,data,len(data),byref(pointer_to_written_data),None)
    windll.Kernel32.CloseHandle(file_handler)
    return

def ReadAFile(file_name=''):

    file_handler=windll.Kernel32.CreateFileA(file_name,0x10000000,0,None,4,0x80,None)
    data=create_string_buffer(4096)
    pointer_to_read_data=c_int(0)
    if(windll.Kernel32.ReadFile(file_handler,byref(data),1024,byref(pointer_to_read_data),None)==0):
            print "Failed"
    print windll.Kernel32.GetLastError()
    windll.Kernel32.CloseHandle(file_handler)
    print data.value
    return

CreateFile("sample.txt","This is a test file!!")
ReadAFile("sample.txt")
```

Comment: Why are you using ctypes to read/write files?

Comment: Just learning how to use ctypes in python as part of a course

Comment: You should call `CloseHandle` after writing the file.

Comment: Hey @ekhumoro I did try that after writing to the file and the result is the same

Comment: Are you able to read a file that you didn't create using ctypes?

Comment: Now that you mention it I tried creating a file using the python interpreter and when I try to read it, it gives me a bunch of hexvalue.

Comment: new_file=open("random.txt","w+") new_file.write("Test") new_file.read() gives me bunch of hex value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works as is after the CloseHandle edit.

When you weren't closing the file handle in `CreateFile()`, the file open in `ReadAFile` failed because the file was already open.  You didn't check the error so your call to `ReadFile` failed.  Now that the code is edited to have the `CloseHandle` in `CreateFile`, it works.  Note you may need to close and re-open your IDE as it may keep a handle open to the file until you kill the process since it was a handle leak (I had that issue).

I also find in ctypes that being explicit and defining `argtypes`, `restype`, and `errcheck` is useful.  `errcheck` especially, since code will throw an error and you don't have to check return values for failure.

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes import wintypes as w

INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = w.HANDLE(-1).value
GENERIC_ALL = 0x10000000
OPEN_ALWAYS = 4
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL = 0x80

_k32 = WinDLL('kernel32',use_last_error=True)
_CreateFileA = _k32.CreateFileA
_WriteFile = _k32.WriteFile
_ReadFile = _k32.ReadFile
_CloseHandle = _k32.CloseHandle

def validate_handle(result,func,args):
    if result == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE:
        raise WindowsError(get_last_error())
    return result

def validate_bool(result,func,args):
    if not result:
        raise WindowsError(get_last_error())

_CreateFileA.argtypes = w.LPCSTR,w.DWORD,w.DWORD,c_void_p,w.DWORD,w.DWORD,w.HANDLE
_CreateFileA.restype = w.HANDLE
_CreateFileA.errcheck = validate_handle
_WriteFile.argtypes = w.HANDLE,c_void_p,w.DWORD,POINTER(w.DWORD),c_void_p
_WriteFile.restype = w.BOOL
_WriteFile.errcheck = validate_bool
_ReadFile.argtypes = w.HANDLE,w.LPVOID,w.DWORD,POINTER(w.DWORD),c_void_p
_ReadFile.restype = w.BOOL
_ReadFile.errcheck = validate_bool
_CloseHandle.argtypes = w.HANDLE,
_CloseHandle.restype = w.BOOL
_CloseHandle.errcheck = validate_bool

def CreateFile(file_name='',data=''):
    file_handler = _CreateFileA(file_name,GENERIC_ALL,0,None,OPEN_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,None)
    written = w.DWORD()
    try:
        _WriteFile(file_handler,data,len(data),byref(written),None)
    finally:
        _CloseHandle(file_handler)

def ReadAFile(file_name=''):
    file_handler = _CreateFileA(file_name,GENERIC_ALL,0,None,OPEN_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,None)
    data = create_string_buffer(4096)
    read = w.DWORD()
    try:
        _ReadFile(file_handler,byref(data),1024,byref(read),None)
    finally:
        _CloseHandle(file_handler)
    print data.value

CreateFile("sample.txt","This is a test file!!")
ReadAFile("sample.txt")
```

Comment: Thanks Mark!! The program works when I run the functions CreateFile and ReadFile as two separate programs. When I try to close the file handler in the CreateFile instance it gives me an invalid handler error and this seems to propogate to the next function as well. Any reason why this is happening ?

Comment: @kvnbni As I mentioned, if you run these scripts in an IDE and have a failure you can get a handle leak.  The code I provided checks for errors and has try/finally so if there is an error on read/write the handle will still get closed.  Also setting `argtypes` and `restype` correctly matters.  On a 64-bit system the default return values is a 32-bit int, and handles are 64-bit.

Comment: Most of this goes over my head. Is there any resource where I can learn more about this. Thank you for your help. Really appreciate this!!

Comment: Consider using `CreateFileW` with `LPCWSTR` instead of `CreateFileA`. In this case, Python 2 ctypes automatically decodes byte strings passed as arguments. Its default conversion is `('mbcs', 'ignore')`, but I recommend switching to strict error handling via `ctypes.set_conversion_mode('mbcs', 'strict')` (2.x only). File paths should be Unicode in Windows, but Python 2 requires a bit of discipline for this. Upgrade to 3.6 if you can.

Comment: Also, don't open a file with `GENERIC_ALL` access just to read it. Use `GENERIC_READ`. In this case you could even use `FILE_READ_DATA` (1), to which `CreateFile` will automatically add the minimum required access: `SYNCHRONIZE` and `FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES`.

Comment: For anyone looks for the API docs, see `CreateFileA` and `CreateFileW` in the Win32 `fileapi`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/