# How do you use win32.WriteFile() the same way as Windows WriteFile API in python?

Tags: python, pywin32, deviceiocontrol

I have a PCI card that uses a pipeline handle and in order to write to its buffers I need to write to its location. I am unfortunately not a software guy but instead have the code given to me in Tcl which my team asked me to convert into Python.
The Tcl scripts uses WriteFile as

```
BOOL WriteFile(
  HANDLE hFile,                    // handle to file to write to
  LPCVOID lpBuffer,                // pointer to data to write to file
  DWORD nNumberOfBytesToWrite,     // number of bytes to write
  LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesWritten,  // pointer to number of bytes written
  LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped        // pointer to structure for overlapped I/O
);
```

While win32.WriteFile only has WriteFile(Handler, Data, Overlap).

How do I create the structure in windows WriteFile in order to use win32.WriteFile()?

Comment: Use the `ctypes` module directly. Have a look at the code in this answer, it should get you started - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48069645/3589122

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listing:

1. [[MS.Learn]: WriteFile function (fileapi.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-writefile)

   > ```c
   > BOOL WriteFile(
   >   [in]                HANDLE       hFile,
   >   [in]                LPCVOID      lpBuffer,
   >   [in]                DWORD        nNumberOfBytesToWrite,
   >   [out, optional]     LPDWORD      lpNumberOfBytesWritten,
   >   [in, out, optional] LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
   > );
   > ```
2. [[GitHub.MHammond]: win32file.WriteFile](https://mhammond.github.io/pywin32/win32file__WriteFile_meth.html)

   > ```py
   > int, int = WriteFile(hFile, data , ol)
   > ```

2<sup>nd</sup> variant is a wrapper over the 1<sup>st</sup>.

2 differences between wrapped and wrapper:

- Lack of *nNumberOfBytesToWrite*: in *C*, data is passed via a (*void**) pointer whose size is unknown, that's why the argument is needed, while in *Python*, the buffer (*char** - or *bytes*) size is already known (embedded into it if you will), so the argument would simply be redundant
- Lack of *lpNumberOfBytesWritten*: in *C*, the return value is the function result status (success / failure) and the written bytes count is placed in an (output) argument, while in *Python* **both of those values are returned** by the function

So, the 2 functions are practically equivalent, the latter is simplified as it takes advantage of *Python* language features.

Here's a trivial example.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

import win32con as wcon
import win32file as wfile


def main(*argv):
    data = b"dummy text\n"
    print("Data length:", len(data))

    hf = wfile.CreateFile("out.txt", wcon.GENERIC_WRITE, 0, None, wcon.CREATE_ALWAYS, 0, None)
    print("Handle:", hf)
    rc, bwr = wfile.WriteFile(hf, data, None)
    print("Return code: {:d}\nBytes Written: {:d}".format(rc, bwr))
    wfile.CloseHandle(hf)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q072945994]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> code00.py
>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py
> Python 3.9.9 (tags/v3.9.9:ccb0e6a, Nov 15 2021, 18:08:50) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Data length: 11
> Handle: <PyHANDLE:580>
> Return code: 0
> Bytes Written: 11
>
> Done.
>
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> code00.py
> out.txt
>
> [prompt]> type out.txt
> dummy text
> ```

Comment: Sure! Let me know if you encounter further issues.